# std::vector is filled up with the same data every time it's used

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, logic

O'k so the following program supposed to take a video file and chop it up to separated frames and save each frame in it's own file, however NOT all the frames should be saved but only the ones with people inside them including about 20 frames before someone enters the frame.

My code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>

void checkForPerson(const cv::Mat &frame, bool &personInside, bool &personInsideLastFrame);
void saveFrame(const cv::Mat &frame, std::vector<const cv::Mat> &frameBuffer, const bool personInsideLastFrame, int &savedFramesCount);

int main(){
    cv::VideoCapture vc;
    cv::Mat currFrame, currFrameBackup, filtered, bg;
    std::vector<const cv::Mat> frameBuffer;
    const cv::String org = "Original";
    const cv::String filt = "Filtered";
    bool personInside = false;
    bool personInsideLastFrame;
    int savedFramesCount = 0;

    vc.open("res/video1.avi");
    if(!vc.isOpened()){
        std::cerr << "cant load video file!\n";
        system("pause");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    vc >> bg; // use first frame as background asuming no people are inside
    if(!bg.data){
        std::cerr << "no frames found\n";
        system("pause");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    cv:cvtColor(bg, bg, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    int c;
    while(vc.read(currFrame) && ((c = cv::waitKey(5)) != 27)){
        cv::cvtColor(currFrame, currFrameBackup, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        filtered = bg - currFrameBackup;
        cv::threshold(filtered, filtered, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);
        cv::Mat erode = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3,3));   //just to clean up the mess a bit
        cv::Mat dilate = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3,3));
        cv::erode(filtered, filtered, erode);
        cv::dilate(filtered, filtered, dilate);
        checkForPerson(filtered, personInside, personInsideLastFrame);
        if(personInside || personInsideLastFrame){
            saveFrame(currFrame, frameBuffer, personInsideLastFrame, savedFramesCount);
        }else{
            if(frameBuffer.size() == 20){
                frameBuffer.erase(frameBuffer.begin());
            }
            frameBuffer.push_back(currFrame);
        }

        cv::imshow(org, currFrame);
        cv::imshow(filt, filtered);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void checkForPerson(const cv::Mat &frame, bool &personInside, bool &personInsideLastFrame){
    if(personInside){
        personInsideLastFrame = true;
    }else{
        personInsideLastFrame = false;
    }
    cv::MatConstIterator_<uchar> it = frame.begin<uchar>();
    cv::MatConstIterator_<uchar> it_end = frame.end<uchar>();
    for(; it != it_end; ++it){
        if((*it) == 255){
            personInside = true;
            return;
        }
    }
    personInside = false;
}

void saveFrame(const cv::Mat &frame, std::vector<const cv::Mat> &frameBuffer, const bool personInsideLastFrame, int &savedFramesCount){
    if(personInsideLastFrame){
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "result/" << ++savedFramesCount << ".jpg";
        cv::imwrite(ss.str(), frame);
    }else{
        for(int i = 0; i<frameBuffer.size(); ++i){
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << "result/" << ++savedFramesCount << ".jpg";
            cv::imwrite(ss.str(), frameBuffer[i]);
            //cv::imshow("tmp", frameBuffer[i]);
            //cv::waitKey(0);
        }
        frameBuffer.clear();
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "result/" << ++savedFramesCount << ".jpg";
        cv::imwrite(ss.str(), frame);
    }
}
```

The `frameBuffer` in the code is used for the 20(if there isn't 20 then then maximum available should be used) pre entry frames as well as to compensate for a few "missed frames" with someone inside. However when is seems that the frames are inserted in to the `frameBuffer` correctly when I save them the very first frame when a person inside was detected is saved 20 times.
I insert a frame to the `frameBuffer` when nothing was detected in the `currentFrame` and use the frames when nothing was detected in the last frame. 
This really fried my brain and I cant seem to see the problem(cant see nothing any more actually),
so someone please tell me I made a stupid mistake and some advice will be really appreciated as well.

I'm sorry if my description is somewhat confusing I couldn't find a better way to explain it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenCV doesn't reallocate a Mat unless it needs to.  A Mat is essentially a smart pointer to a buffer. If you push_back a Mat into a vector, that is like making a copy of the pointer to the same buffer. Then you reuse the buffer and the pointer in the vector is pointing to the new content!

You need to clone the Mat when you push it onto the vector:

```
frameBuffer.push_back(currFrame.clone());
```

Comment: OMG how could I be so stupid! Thank you very much! I knew I was doing something stupid!